# Help with understanding Check Digit Validations

Tags: algorithms

I'm not sure if I'm posting in the correct section, but I wanted to learn about CDVs, how the weightings work, and the computation.

I'm reviewing how a system is configured and looking to add a new range of numbers, but it fails validation, someone mentioned that it's probably linked to the weightings.

The CDV is using the Modulus 11 computation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The weightings are subjective and depend on the requirements of the system, there is nothing to be answered without more information.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible algorithms for checksums and "check digits".  We can't answer those questions without knowing which one is being used in your setting.

I suggest doing some more background reading on the subject.  See, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_digit, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damm_algorithm, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verhoeff_algorithm.

Comment: Hi, I don't know what algorithm but I can provide you with the system settings that check the reference number, indicating a pass or fail, it has the weightings and how it computes it.

Not sure if I can attach an image or Word doc, can't see any options to insert.

Thanks.